# Why hashing is required for unordered_map and not in map?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, stl, hashmap

I am new to C++, and I know that unordered_map uses hashing and map uses red black tree. I am confused why hashing is required for unordered_map whereas not in map. What is the reason?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct hash_pair {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator()(const pair<T1, T2>& p) const
    {
        auto hash1 = hash<T1>{}(p.first);
        auto hash2 = hash<T2>{}(p.second);
        return hash1 ^ hash2;
    }
};
  
int main()
{
    unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int, hash_pair> hmap1;
    hmap1[{1,1}]=2;
    
    if (hmap1.find({1,1})!=hmap1.end()) cout<<"Value found :"<<hmap1[{1,1}]<<endl;
    if (hmap1.find({0,0})==hmap1.end()) cout<<"Value not  found"<<endl;
    
    map<pair<int, int>, int> hmap2;
    hmap2[{2,2}]=4;
    
    if (hmap2.find({2,2})!=hmap2.end()) cout<<"Value found :"<<hmap2[{2,2}]<<endl;
    if (hmap2.find({0,0})==hmap2.end()) cout<<"Value not  found"<<endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

**Value found :2**

**Value not  found**

**Value found :4**

**Value not  found**

Comment: Do you know what a red-black tree is and how it works?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I know ihow it works.Is there anything I am missing

Comment: Looks like you do not understand how RB trees work, otherwise, it would be immediately obvious to you why `std::map` doesn't need a hash function.

Comment: Obligatory links to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Together they amplify each other's worst effects and can easily turn a program into a minefield of weird. Use with caution, and when you have a problem with your code they should be among the first things to be removed.

Comment: If you are trying to learn C++ from coding competition sites, don't. Teaching is not what they are for and as a result they *really* suck at it. Save yourself time and get a [couple good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You'll save yourself a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is simple:  a `std::map` looks up an item inside its red-black tree by starting at the root of the tree and recursively moving down the tree, comparing items at each node of the tree against the key-item (using the `<` operator), and using the result of the comparison to decide which child-node to recurse to, until it eventually arrives at the node it is looking for and returns the result (or alternatively until it arrives at a leaf node without ever encountering the requested key, in which case it will return an error).  At no point in that process is it necessary to compute a hash-code of anything.

A `std::unordered_map`, on the other hand, doesn't use a tree-style data structure.  Instead it uses hashing to compute where in its internal data-array it should look for the specified key.  In order to do, that it needs to be able to compute a hash code for that key; it can then compute the modulo of that hash-code to obtain an array-index to start looking in.